# Screen command not properly running in bash while using .desktop file ( Launcher for that bash )

Tags: bash, ubuntu-18.04, launcher

I am trying to run a bash script using .desktop file.

Bash script contains screen commands.
When executing (./script.sh), it works as expected.
But when running the script using .desktop file screen commands are not giving actual output.

My shell script file

```sh
projects=/path/to/projects
cd $projects/project1
screen -dmS project-1 ./mvnw
cd $projects/project2
screen -dmS project-2 sudo ../bin/eim_app ../config/config.json 2 >> ../../err.txt
```

My .desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My Projects 1&2
Version=1.0
Comment=Start script for My Projects
Exec=/path/to/script/script.sh
Encoding=UTF-8
Icon=
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
```

My expectation is to get two detached screens which are running my two projects by simply clicking the "My Project 1&2" Icon.

Comment: Try adding `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of your script and/or making your Exec line: `Exec=/bin/bash -c "/path/to/script/script.sh"`

Comment: thanks for your commends.
But, I am already using  -- #!/usr/bin/env bash -- @ first of the script

Is there any difference btw #!/bin/bash and #!/usr/bin/env bash

Comment: I think there is a problem with my project 1.
When i open it directly, working fine.
But When try to open in screen , screen is terminating..
I am looking to that...